# How to process multiple tensorflow models android

Tags: android, tensorflow, model, gesture-detection

I am working on the app which will take the camera input and process with tensorflow model(for **gesture detection**) which will give the bounding box output. I have to take the output from the first model and should process the same to the second model(**identify gesture**). I could not find anything. please guide me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Simple explanation is a prediction with target conditions preferred path.
Q-networks may return more than action but expect values or pausing action that is because it can share loads.